# Facing an issue with Increment operator in PHP

Tags: php, operators, increment

I am facing an unexpected issue with the increment operator in PHP. Please take a look at the given two programs:

1st Program:

```
<?php
  $a=5;
  $a++;
  echo $a;
?>
```

it prints **6**, which I clearly understood that what was happened, it just incremented the value with 1.

2nd Program:

```
<?php
  $a=5;
  $b = $a++;     // just assigned incremented value to a new variable b.
  echo $b;
?>
```

it prints **5**.

Now here is the confusion, I just assigned the incremented value to the variable, so I should print 6 - why it is printing 5?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/6521116)

Comment: In this second scenario $a value not incremening,it will treated as $a is assigning to $b. So value is 5 only.

Comment: `$a++`, use the expression value first then auto increment. while `++$a` auto increment first then use the expression value.

Comment: Please read about the Post-increment operator [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).

Comment: @RaMeSh yes you are right, but why did it happen, it should also incremented the value. I know there is something i am not getting, i am just trying to know what's that.

Comment: @Insomania How do you know it didn't increment `$a`? You're printing `$b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting 5 because in postfix operator first it will assign the value to `$b` after that their value will be incremented. SO first `$a` is assigning to `$b` after that `$a` value will incremented